# Шара — что это такое?

Tags: этимология

Просторечное "на шару" значит "даром". А что такое изначально "шара"?

Comment: По М. Фасмеру:
"выварки кирпичного чая", сиб. (Даль). Из калм. šаr – то же. 

Comment: Не очень понятно, как это значение стало обозначать что-то бесплатное, халявное.

Comment: я не совсем понимаю, при чём здесь доходы аглицкого короля? какая связь между бесплатным поеданием пирожков и доходами аглицкого короля? Объясните, пожалуйста!

Comment: Да! А какая связь?

Answer (score 4):

Для меня вопрос происхождения "шары" совсем не очевиден.

Для начала разберемся со значением. Понятие "на шару" не совсем синонимично "на халяву". В моём понимании - это не просто на дармовщинку, а как бы из общего котла, но без взноса в него. Вспоминается английское "to share" - делить, разделять. Но английский вряд ли мог служить основой для жаргонного слова, а в немецком я подобного не знаю.

В этом смысле версия происхождения от "шаромыжки" вроде бы подходяща. Но шаромыжка, шаромыжник - слово достаточно богатое, вряд ли может быть сведено к халяве. В примере из Гоголя вообще другой смысл. Там не халява, а вместе, "на пАру", как хорошие друзья. Это и есть главное значение слова, во всяком случае - во времена Гоголя. По всему этому и версия происхождения шары от шеромыги, шерамыжки весьма сомнительна.

//===

Меня поправили насчет Гоголя. В письме Тряпичкину - да, согласен. Там шерамыжка = халяве.

Comment: >Но английский вряд ли мог служить основой для жаргонного слова

Теперь - служит. "Шара" - на жаргоне системных администраторов - "разделяемый ресурс" или "общий ресурс".

Comment: Да это не новость. 
Новостью будет, есои кто-то докажет, что этимологически это та же шара, что и в старые времена.

Answer (score 4):

Сомневаюсь, что "на шерамыжку" - это "в дружеском кругу". "Шаромыжники" - попрошайки, халявщики; слово происходит, как принято считать, из лексикона французских солдат, которые к концу Отечественной войны 1812 года побирались, начиная свои просьбы словами "шер ами" - "дорогой друг".
В цитате из Гоголя выражение "обедали на шерамыжку" скорее усиливает предыдущие слова о том, как Хлестаков с другом бедствовали.

Comment: Про шермыжника - всё правильно. Но во времена Гоголя французский знали. И "шер ами" к шарамыжнику не сводили.

Answer (score 2):

Если шару не искать в французском попрошайничестве, тогда придется её искать в сленге, образованном из еврейских слов.
Имеет место такая версия: **шара, на шару** — бесплатно. Ивр. (שאר, שארים шеар, шеарим) — остатки.
То, что остается у продавца, непригодное для продажи, и он оставляет это на прилавке для бедных. Согласно еврейской традиции на поле необходимо оставлять несжатую полоску — שאר — шеар — остаток, чтобы бедные могли собирать колосья.

Источник: [**Происхождение воровского жаргона** | fishki.net](http://fishki.net/1406924-proishozhdenie-vorovskogo-zhargona-spasibo-evrejam.html)

Answer (score 1):

Возможны два варианта этимологии (возможно, что они как-то пересекаются).

1. Шара - это остатки заварки, вторичная заварка чая. Таким образом, можно сказать, что шара - это что-то не самое качественное, но и платить за нее не нужно.
2. Шара - это одно из обозначений банды, шайки. Таким образом, "на шару" - это на всех, на весь коллектив.

Тут, кстати, вполне может быть согласование и с первым вариантом - чай на шаре на шару.

Comment: 1. Невозможно. Время вощникновени того и другого прикиньте. 2. Аналогично.

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю, что слово "шар" имеет чисто славянскую этимологию и родственно такому латинскому слову (напишу его в английской форме), как sphere. И "шар", и "sphere" суть славянский и латинский варианты одного и того же индоевропейского корня.

Comment: *И "шар", и "sphere" суть славянский и латинский варианты одного и того же индоевропейского корня.* - во-первых, это надо обосновать. Во-вторых, это не ответ на вопрос. Вопрос был о выражении "на шАру".

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "на шару" является вырожденным восточным "хашаром". Хашар - осадная толпа. "Взять город хашаром" выродилось в русском языке в "взять город на шару". Выписка из энциклопедии в отношении осадных технологий монголов:
Отдельным средством в осадном искусстве монголов была осадная толпа. Хашар, или буквально «толпа», прием давно известный на Востоке. Он заключается в том, что войско завоевателей использует согнанное население завоевываемой области на тяжелых вспомогательных работах, чаще всего осадных. Другой особенностью применения хашара монголами было использование его как непосредственного орудия штурма, его первой волны. Этот бесчеловечный прием помимо основной цели – заставить обороняющихся израсходовать средства обороны по людям хашара, сохранив собственно монголов, давал еще дополнительный психологический эффект воздействия на защитников. Сопротивляться людям, согнанным в хашар, было трудно, если не невозможно: «Если пленные возвращались, не доставив прикрытия к стене, им рубили головы. Поэтому они были настойчивы и наконец пробили брешь».
Таким образом, "взять на шару (хашаром)" означает добыть, что-либо не затрачивая собственных ресурсов, за чужой счет.

Comment: Крайне недостоверно. А аргументы к тому есть, кроме частичного фонетического сходства?

Comment: Кроме фонетического сходства имеется полное смысловое совпадение.

Comment: Кроме того, слово "хашар" с несколько изменившимся смыслом никуда из тюркских языков не исчез (см. Википедию). Учитываю длительный период совместного проживания в рамках одной страны возможно и более позднее заимствование или длящееся во времени заимствование в течении различных поколений.

Answer (score 0):

"На шару" (от английского слова SHARE) - адаптированное под русское произношение. Т.е поделиться или, как многие любят произносить, - "на халяву". Еще одна из форм этого же слова - это "расшарить". То есть дать доступ/поделиться.

Comment: Кем и для кого адаптированное? У русских есть уже ШАРА, ШАР — краска, цвет.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле задолго до войны с Наполеоном в русском языке было слово «шаромыга». Оно произошло от слова «шарма», которое в переводе на современный русский означает «даром» или «бесплатно». Так что шаромыжниками мы с вами называли любителей поживиться за чужой счет испокон веку.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть ссылки на источники эгого "самого дела". Интерент об этой "шарме" ничего не знает.  Да и суффикс "ыг(а)" необъясним.

Answer (score 0):

Обычное деловое выражение в "старой" Одессе. Получить на шару - долю прибыли пропорционально вложенной своей части в общий капитал (англ. share), более ничем не участвуя в организации и (или) реализации предприятия - т. е. без труда.

Comment: Откуда в Одессе английский?

Answer (score -1):

В древнейших источниках, датируемых 700годами и описывающих Хазарский каганат четко написано: ШАРА-закон хазарский. Дословно "СВОЕГО РА". От этого слова происходит современное арабское "ШАР"АТ"  -(шариат), дословно "Шара-установившийся"
А слово ""Шаромыжники"  -это попрошайническое слово на фр.языке (на фр.языке-подайте мне милостыню), появившееся в русском языке  и произносимое фр.солдатами Наполеона при отступлении от Москвы (1812г)

Comment: Где хазары - и где шара)))